# How to modify default meta link format

Tags: post-meta

I want to change the URL for the author meta next to all the posts.
I don’t know where WP pulls this from, but it’s now a link to (essentially) ../author/%POSTAUTHOR%, or whatever the field name is. I want to change it to ../members/%POSTAUTHOR% permanently for all posts.
How do I do this?
I should note I'm using the Customify theme.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can manually change the `$wp_rewrite->author_base` which stores the author base (the `author` part in the URL) or the [Edit Author Slug](https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/) plugin might be easier for you.

Comment: Great, thanks! I found a functional snippet at https://letswp.io/how-to-change-author-base-in-wordpress/ that got me what I needed as well.